# Where can I download ubuntu-10.04-destktop-amd64.iso file?

Tags: downloads, iso

I can't find `ubuntu-10.04-destktop-amd64.iso` on http://www.ubuntu.com/download.

Where I can find it? Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Here you go.  Just click on the link to download...

**10.04.4**

64 Bit:
http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.04.4/ubuntu-10.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso

32 Bit:
http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.04.4/ubuntu-10.04.4-desktop-i386.iso

**10.04.3**

64 Bit:
http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso

32 Bit:
http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.3-desktop-i386.iso

**10.04.2**

64 Bit:
http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso

32 Bit:
http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.2-desktop-i386.iso

**10.04.1**

64 Bit:
http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso

32 Bit:
http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.1-desktop-i386.iso

**10.04**

64 Bit:
http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/lucid/ubuntu-10.04-desktop-amd64.iso

32 Bit:
http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/lucid/ubuntu-10.04-desktop-i386.iso

---

From:
http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/lucid/

---

"Intel x86" means **32-bit** and "AMD64" means **64 bit**, If you didn't know that.  I don't get why you want to get 10.04.x because it is a EOL (End of life) releases on the desktop and remember that getting updated software to work can be hard so use this to help you with that "[How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)".  I also  recommended you not to use it as a daily os but to just show it is just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 10.04 Desktop can be downloaded from http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/

Comment: That no longer has ***desktop*** images.

Comment: However **http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.04.0/** has: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.04.0/ubuntu-10.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso

Comment: You should edit your answer ..

Answer (score 1):

this is the link you want. http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.4-server-amd64.iso . just click at that link to download the ISO. But havent found desktop ISO but you can install the desktop later . To choose the desktop you need please look at this question.

[What kinds of desktop environments and shells are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available)

Answer (score 1):

Just go to http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/lucid/ and scroll down to the release you want. [Here's a direct link](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso) to that iso.